# Application of Fourier Derivative theorem

Tags: fourier-transform

The [Fourier Derivative theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Differentiation) states that

$ \widetilde{\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}} = ik\widetilde{f(k)}$

where the over-tilde denotes application of the Fourier transform.

My question is what if $f(x)$ is of the form $f(x) = g(x)\dfrac{dh(x)}{dx}$ and I want to apply the transform

$ \cal{F} \left[ {\dfrac{d}{dx} \left(g(x)\dfrac{dh(x)}{dx}  \right)} \right] $

I was initially inclined to just apply the derivative theorem to each operator, however the fact that $g(x)$ is a function of x is causing me to doubt this is correct.

Do I have to apply the product rule first to give

$\dfrac{d}{dx} \left(g(x)\dfrac{dh(x)}{dx}  \right) = g(x)\dfrac{d^2h(x)}{dx^2} +  \dfrac{d g(x)}{dx}\dfrac{dh(x)}{dx}$

Can I then apply the derivative theorem to each operator, or does the product of gradients forbid this?

Does the fact that $g(x)$ is dependent on x forbid me from applying Fourier transforms?

Comment: You need to make sure each of the products $gh'$, $(gh')'$, $gh''$, and $g'h'$ belong to a space where the Fourier transform is defined. In that case you will have
$$\widehat{(gh')'} = \widehat{gh''} + \widehat{g'h'}.$$ The Fourier transform of a product can be expressed using a convolution.

Comment: Assuming they belong to a space...does this imply I can apply the derivative theorem? Something of the form $-gk^2\hat{h} - k^2\hat{g}\hat{h}$ ? I want to know if/how I can transfer the derivative operators such that I can get an algebraic equation.

Comment: If dealing with tildes over long expressions is a pain, the notation $\tilde f = {\cal F}(f)$ is also used.

Comment: The Fourier transform of a product is the convolution of the Fourier transforms

Comment: OK...so assume the space exists, then $\widehat{(gh')'} = \widehat{gh''} + \widehat{g'h'} = \widehat{(gh')'} = \widehat{g}*\widehat{h''} + \widehat{g'} * \widehat{h'}$. I can then apply the derivative theorem to get $ \widehat{(gh')'}  = \widehat{g}*(-k^2 \widehat{h}) + -ik\widehat{g} * -ik \widehat{h}$. Is that right?

Comment: I see my assumption has been up-voted, which leads me to believe I'm on the right track. Can you recommend a text book or something where I can learn more about this?